# why my echo doesn't work before a header function header(location:home.php);

Tags: php, header, echo

why my echo doesn't work here in this code?It goes directly to the function header().

```
if($result){
    echo("<script> alert('User Successfull Added')</script>");
    header('location:home.php');
}
```

Comment: Because you have echo above header, that is considered output. You need to put your echo under header in order for it to (probably) work. 'Tis the "Law of the Land" ;-)

Comment: It does work it is just that the browser never gets the instruction before going to home.php

Comment: @jeff I beg to differ. That will produce a "headers already sent" error message.

Comment: What do you expect the result to be here? Do something *while* redirecting? Nope, can't do both.

Comment: Because you redirect him immediately..

Comment: @Fred Not necessarily, depending on the output buffer settings.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it still doesnt work even if i put the echo under the header..

Comment: @deceze Now "that", I did not know, *till now*. I'm going to ask my good friend Mr. Google ;-) Don't want to tie up this thread.

Comment: even if i put the header outside the if block it still doesnt work..

Comment: @jmjassy27 Exactly. So why do you want to use that piece of code, what's your goal? If anything it would need to be put inside an `if` condition.

Comment: @jmjassy27 Have a look at my [**example below**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18372091/1415724).

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your code example work, you need to put it inside an `if/else` condition like so, if you want it to work, but since I only see what you posted as code, am putting this in as an example:

```
<?php

if($result){
    echo("<script>alert('User Successfully Added')</script>");

    echo("<script>window.location = 'home.php';</script>");

}

else {

    header('Location: elsewhere.php');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually thy echo is working. but we cant see the message because at the same time the page redirects to the home.php page.

If you want to alert to display the alert message use jquery post. or php session variable

Comment: so what should i do..??

Comment: May methods are for this. jquery post, confirm box php session etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to both display the alert & redirect to home.php, why don't you just try setting a SESSION (or other global variable) and then check if it's set at the start of the redirected page?

Such as:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usercreated']="Y";
    header('Location: elsewhere.php');
?>
```

and then on home.php at the start of your php code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usercreated'])){
        echo("<script> alert('User Successfully Added')</script>");
    }
    //....
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I can't add comment here. But I think what you want to do needs Java and replace  alert() with confirm()

```
var r=confirm("User Successfull Added")
  if (r==true) // if user click OK
    {
      window.location.assign("home.php")
    }
      else // user click Cancel
    {

    }
```

Comment: JavaScript that is, not Java

Comment: I don't think a confirmation dialog is needed here.

Comment: then may be <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=home.php" /> in order to delay the page and have enough time to display the alert() dialog.